# Перевернутый рабочий стол linux mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Поставил вчера ssd, на него mint 18 cinnamom. Бывают случаи при включении, после ввода пароля весь экран полностью переворачивается вместе с указателем. Как решать?

Comment: этап1: создать другого пользователя и сравнить.

Answer (score 1):

Убедитесь что в настройках вашей видеокарты не выставлено вращение или отражение (даже если не выставлено, можете через эти же настройки сами перевернуть экран как вам нужно).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

> Как решать?

Очень просто - перевернуть монитор :-)

Ну а если серьёзно, то я сталкивался с такой проблемой в давние 90-е годы. После загрузки системы изображение переворачивалось. Ну, там был тогда ещё диковинный зверь под названием "вирус".

Из того, что Вы сообщили, следует два вывода:

1. Раз переворот происходит после логина, то проблема, скорее всего, кроется в .profile или .bashrc в Вашем домашнем каталоге.
2. Раз проблема появилась после подключения ssd, то вредоносный код, скорее всего - там.

Ну и мои рекомендации:

1. Переименуйте .bashrc и .profile во что-то типа .bashrc.bac и .profile.bac
2. Перегрузите систему. Если проблема исчезла - внимательно просмотрите содержимое этих файлов на предмет ссылок на файлы, находящиеся на ssd и удалите их.
3. Перезагрузитесь, восстановив имена файлов.

Если не помогло - Значит ещё во время загрузки системы (до логина) с Вашего ssd грузится какая-то гадость и остаётся в памяти до момента логина.

Для выяснения - не выполняя логин в графической оболочке, зайди на комп по ssh или telnet - посмотрите список процессов в памяти. Если такой возможности нет - попытайтесь прервать нормальный ход загрузки с графической оболочкой и выйти в режим командной строки.

Comment: Очень странный ответ...